# Is there any way to clear cache when making REST API request?

Tags: rest-api

I’m using the WooCommerce REST API to create, read and delete products on an iOS app. Everything is listed properly, I can create and list items but when reading it does not give me the latest data. Although I'm making reference to WooCommerce, this is more of a REST API question since I will also list the WordPress media library.

I’m using Alamofire which is a framework to make URL requests and I have it set to no cache. The only way I get the latest data is if I purge cache via cPanel.

The HTTP request is using this basic format: https:// example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products with consumer_key and consumer_secret as parameters and for HTTP headers: "Accept": "application/json" and "Cache-Control": "no-store".

Is there any parameter that I could add to the URL that would clear cache OR force to send me the latest data?